# Jquery AJAX with codeigniter, always returns error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to write a script that will add the video currently being viewed to a database of favourites. However every time it runs, an error is returned, and nothing is stored in the database.

Here is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#addfav").click(function() {

 var form_data = {heading: $("#vidheading").text(), embed : $("#vidembed").text()};

  jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"localhost/stumble/site/add_to_fav.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: form_data,
      success: function (data){
          console.log(data.status);
          alert("This Video Has Been Added To Your Favourites")

      },
      error: function (data){
        console.log(data.status); 
        alert("You Must Be Logged In to Do That")
      }
  });
})

})
```

The add_to_fav.php is this...

```
public function add_to_fav(){

      $this->load->model('model_users');
      $this->model_users->add_favs();    

}
```

And the add_favs function is below

```
public function add_favs(){
    if($this->session->userdata('username')){
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
      'title' => $this->input->post('heading'),
      'embed' => $this->input->post('embed')
      );

      $query = $this->db->insert('fav_videos',$data);
        if($query){
      $response_array['status'] = 'success';
      echo json_encode($response_array);
        }}else {

          $response_array['status'] = 'error';
          echo json_encode($response_array);
      }

  }
```

Thank you for the input, this has me stuck but I am aware it may be something relatively simple, my hunch is that it is something to do with returning success or error.

Comment: Why are you posting to an actual php file? Codeignitor is an MVC framework, so you should be posting to some route thats mapped to a controller function.

Comment: Try and remove .php from the ajax url

Comment: I am posting to a controller function, it is called add_to_fav. The same problem arises after removing the .php from ajax url

Comment: "every time it runs, an error is returned" - what is the error? what is the value of data? Does the insert take place? Is the database getting updated and only the frontend says there is an error?

Comment: Sorry, I meant an error response is returned, as apposed to success, when the title and embed code of the video have been successfully stored in the database - right now, no insert takes place

Comment: @RobertDarby So the data **is** correctly stored in the db, but the error function fires? Is that correct? If so, does the console.log(data.status) show success as well?

Comment: no, the data is not stored in the db right now.

Comment: please change your error function to simply: `error:function(resp){console.log(resp);}` and post the results from the console

Comment: this is returned in the console 
Object { readyState=4, responseText="<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html la... </div>\n</body>\n</html>", status=404, more...}

Comment: @RobertDarby - I think this line `$query = $this->db->insert('fav_videos',$data);` is creating an error, maybe the sql statement is incorrect. You should print the SQL, try executing it directly from your SQL interface and check.

Comment: @RobertDarby 404 error means your routing is cocked up, which is what i suggested all along. The ajax url is clearly wrong.

Comment: What is the controller name ? Is it site ? In that case the url should be http://localhost/stumble/Site/add_to_fav

Comment: the controller is called site

Comment: perhaps if i use the base_url function?

Comment: Try Site instead of site also add http://

Comment: base_url won't work in javascript

Comment: YES! Capitalising Site and adding http:// did the trick

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, for your solutions and patience

Comment: Glad that it worked...can you pls select my answer.

Comment: What is interesting now, is that even when the console returns "error", the success message appears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#addfav").click(function() {

 var form_data = {heading: $("#vidheading").text(), embed : $("#vidembed").text()};

  jQuery.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"http://localhost/stumble/Site/add_to_fav",
      dataType: "json",
      data: form_data,
      success: function (data){
          console.log(data.status);
          alert("This Video Has Been Added To Your Favourites")

      },
      error: function (data){
        console.log(data.status); 
        alert("You Must Be Logged In to Do That")
      }
  });
})

})
```

Also to use base_url in javascript. In your template view :-

```
<script>
 window.base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

Now you can use base_url in all your ajax scripts.